# How can I write e-mails in colored (and any size) letters with mail.ru app for Android?

Tags: email

> How can I write e-mails in colored (and any size) letters with mail.ru app for Android?

I tried:

I downloaded Microsoft Word app. And I wrote text there with colored letters.Then I copied it.When I paste it to mail.ru, the same thing was happened again. The letters were colorless and shrunk. I know, this is possible in windows operation in PC.

> Is there no way to do this on Android?

Comment: Set text format to HTML or something like that if it's possible.